# Querying a large Postgres correlation table

Tags: postgresql

I have a large Postgres table (150gb+) which stores a large correlation matrix between two variables val1 and val2. For example:

```
val1   |   val2  |  distance  
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
  0    |    1    |     10
  0    |    2    |     21
  0    |    3    |     13
  1    |    2    |     65
  1    |    3    |     43
  2    |    3    |     56
```

The pair (val1,val2) is the composite primary key for the table. I'm finding that when I run the query below the query executes in under 35ms.

```
SELECT *
FROM sliding_window_distances
WHERE (val1 = 10000)
```

But when I search using val2, it doesn't execute and times out.

```
SELECT *
FROM sliding_window_distances
WHERE (val2 = 10000)
```

Ideally I want to run the query below, so that I have all records for the specific value (10000 in my example)

```
SELECT *
FROM sliding_window_distances
WHERE (val1 = 10000)
OR (val2 = 10000)
```

I'm not sure how to speed up the query.

Comment: Add an additional UNIQUE constraint on (val2, val1). (this will create an index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to clean up the stale cache data before doing any other actions that cause timeout.

First type:

```
VACUUM ANALYZE sliding_window_distances;
```

Also you should use *secondary indexes* in your table. Creating an index dramatically **speed up** the query operations.

To creating an index without locking out writes to the table:

```
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY windows_dist_index ON sliding_window_distances (val2);
```

You may also define additional `UNIQUE` constraint like below:

```
ALTER TABLE sliding_window_distances ADD UNIQUE (val2, val1);
```

[PostgreSQL Documentation on Indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createindex.html)

Comment: Hi GökcanD, Thanks..Creating the index appears to timeout...the table is very large.

Comment: @kPow989 Are there any error logs that we can see? Also, please try the "vacuum" solution too.

Comment: Thanks..the composite key (val1, val2) is already unique...I just get a timeout when creating the index..I've read they could also take hours to complete right?

Comment: @kPow989 Try to add WHERE clause to the CREATE INDEX statement such as WHERE val1<10000   . If it works also use that statement with val1>10000. Also check the solution as verified and upvote if it helped you.

Comment: I think the VACUUM ANALYZE sliding_window_distances did make a significant difference..the query is now running much faster..thanks!